# Ignore website/store in search results, search all products from all shops

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, catalogsearch, search

I would like to expand the search over all websites/stores in the installation. 
In

```
Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer
```

I tried to remove `->addStoreFilter()` from the collection but this doesn't work...

Any hints where i should start looking for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by commenting below function in following file:

path :`\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Query.php` and 
function :`getResultCollection()`

on above function you will find the `addStoreFilter` line just comment it and try.

Before changing it copy the file to the local code pool on the same path.

path :`\app\code\local\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Query.php`

Comment: You really should learn how to rewrite the function in your own extension.  The app/code/local/Mage thing works but is not the best way to do it.  Not related to this,  but it doesn't work with controllers so if you ever encounter a controller rewrite you'll already know the basics.

Comment: I (for my part) am aware of rewriting. But to keep it simple, I just posted the original file. Anyway, this seems to do nothing either...